# Is there any way to work with a Node stream as an iterable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I’m writing a tool which processes a bunch of text passed in to `stdin`, each line is an “entry”. I’d like to make my code more functional, so I’d like to treat the set of lines as a “sequence” or “iterable” and iterate over it using `reduce`.

I’m currently using the [Node](http://nodejs.org/) module [LineStream](https://github.com/shinout/LineStream) to process `stdin` as a set of lines, but it works by dispatching a `data` event for each line — which is fine, it’s implementing the [Readable Stream](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/streams.html#readable_Stream) interface.

So I’m currently doing kind of a very “manual” reduce by passing the interim value in to my function every time the `data` event fires:

```
var windows = [];

linestream.on('data', function(line) {
  return windows = rollup(windows, extractDate(line), argv.w);
});

linestream.on('end', function() {
  return process.stdout.write(toCsv(windows));
});

process.stdin.resume();
```

But it’d be more functional to do something like:

```
linestream.lines.reduce(rollup, []);

function rollup(windows, line) {
    // would return a new interim or final value
}
```

Of course, I could “collect” all the lines into a regular array and then reduce it, but I tried that and it uses way too much memory when I’m running my tool on a large dataset — so something like iteration over the stream is really what’s necessary.

I guess what I’m asking is whether it’s possible to write a Node function/module which would do this, or whether one exists already.

Thanks!

Comment: this reminds me of http://blip.tv/jsconfeu/jed-schmidt-getting-functional-with-fab-4399811

Comment: Just found [getline](http://www.cvine.plus.com/getline/index.html) which seems like it could be part of the puzzle, since it has a `next()` method so it seems like an “iterable”. But the more I think about this, the more I think it might be possible without support for “iterables” in V8 — _or_, I suppose, I could write my own implementation of `reduce`… hmm…

Comment: getline appears to be doing basically what you're doing, but is under the assumption that the data is not as structured. If you can assume that your data is definitely 1 line per event, there is no need to use getline (or so it appears).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to make this more functional, because you're dealing with asynchronicity.

For `linestream.lines` to exist, I think one of two things would need to happen:

- In-memory buffer of every line, which you've already said takes up too much memory
- a new language construct that would allow an asynchronous control flow to appear like a synchronous one.

I suppose you could do this (assuming using jquery or some other promise api):

```
var op = (function(){

    var windows = []
        ,done = $.deferred();

    linestream.on('data', function(line) {
      return windows = rollup(windows, extractDate(line), argv.w);
    });

    linestream.on('end', function() {
      process.stdout.write(toCsv(windows));
      return done.resolve(windows);
    });

    process.stdin.resume();

    return done.promise();

})();
```

But really that's just hiding things.

Or, you could use maybe use something like [Rx](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/b4c6511d-132d-430e-9a5c-b345465bad83), or wait until [generators](http://taskjs.org/) are around.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what `rollup` is supposed to do, but as others have noted, you can't have a reduce function that expects to have all the data at once without first having all the data at once and in memory.

What you can do, however is just do your reduce logic in the data event callback.  If it needs more state such as the last value or the total number of values, you can keep that data in a closure around the callback.

For example, here is a rolling average on an async stream of numbers.

```
var total = 0;
var items = 0;
var average;

stream.on('data', function (line) {
  var num = parseInt(line, 10);
  total += line;
  items++;
  average = total / items;
});

stream.on('end', function () {
  console.log("The average is %s", average);
});
```

In this example, I'm getting the relevant data out of each line as it comes in and keeping around enough extra data to always know my context.  In this case, I'm calculating averages and thus need to know how many total items there are.

Comment: Thanks Tim, great answer. Just to clarify, my reduce function doesn’t expect to have all the data at once — I’m pretty sure that’s not how `reduce` works in general. My current solution is similar to your suggestion, and it’s working great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing it the functional way. You're listening to events, and running a function when that event triggers, it can't be more functional than that.

You're second example doesn't change the function, it's still as functional as the first example. What it does change however, is the source that the function is run on. Reduce relies on a big array of data, all in memory at the same time, which, as you say, lead to a very big memory footprint.

I would just stay with the default node way if I were you.

Comment: I don’t know about that, because I’m mutating `windows` with each invocation of my `data` event handler. This is indeed what `reduce` does internally, but as I understand it, it’s a functional best practice to avoid mutation as much as possible in “userland” code.

Comment: What are you going to do with the array of windows?

Comment: `linestream.on('end', function() {
  return process.stdout.write(toCsv(windows));
});`

Comment: They I would write to file incrementally too. Either yourself (CSV isn't that advanced), or via this plugin: https://github.com/koles/ya-csv

Comment: I can’t write the output incrementally, because I’m calculating something — the result is only correct once I’ve processed all of the input.

Comment: What kind of calculation? Could you do it incrementally?